# Error Restore database to secondary - Log Shipping

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I am new as a DBA. I want to ask. I want to create new log shipping a database 17815 from server primary to server secondary. I create new log shipping with right-click on database 17815. when I click ok,  but I get this error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The file 'M:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\PREUATPSSHSOH123CAB_Data.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database '13722'.
```

So what can I do? I was trying to restore manually with the restore command, and restore was successful. However, when I try to create new log shipping again, the error is the same.

Comment: Are you setting up log shipping between two servers? Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630279/listing-information-about-all-database-files-in-sql-server/9630439) to check what database is using the same file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the database 13722 is using the same data files.
You have to rename the files of the 13722 database.

use this guide for file rename:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/09/01/sql-server-rename-physical-database-file-name-for-any-database/

Always backup before this kind of changes!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

i am confusing why 13722 is using the same data files. 
cause name data files is different

M:\MyData\17815_Data.mdf -> database 17815
M:\MyData\13722_Data.mdf -> database 13722

Comment: who is using this PREUATPSSHSOH123CAB_Data.mdf?

Comment: i dont know why the error say "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The file 'M:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\PREUATPSSHSOH123CAB_Data.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database '13722'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)"  sir

Comment: can you share the logshipping script?

Comment: this step that i use to create logshipping.
1. right click on database (on primary server)
2. click properties
3. click transaction log shipping, and edit backup setting, and another.

Comment: please provide full scripts of the configuration done. (save as a script)